# c++ developing BankAccount structure that creates a customer, transactions, accounts (uni assign help)

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, parameters

Boys and girls, I thank you in advance for your help. C++ issues again. I have university assignment struggles and I am building on a previous question posted on stack a couple of days back in this separate post due to stack policy.

My Question: Below is my code that is not working can anybody help me to make it work? And what am I missing? (I have a feeling I am missing a lot).

I have the functions and structs in separate header files and the “int main” in a .ccp. I am using vis studio to do this. Please don’t think I am trying to get others to do my assignment. Below is my code followed by the assignment task sheet (for further information purposes only).

```
>     CODE
>     
>     // the int main must be my output to screen
>     int main()
>     {
>     Customer* Mary = CreateCustomer("Mary Jones", "235718", "5074");
>     Customer* John = CreateCustomer("John Smith", "375864", "3251");
>     Account* MaryAccount = CreateAccount(*Mary, "06-3121-10212357", "01/03/2014", 100);
>     Account* JohnAccount = CreateAccount(*John, "06-3121-10213758", "10/03/2014");
>     RecordWithdraw(MaryAccount, CreateTransaction("01/03/2014", "ATM Withdrawal", 50) );
>     RecordDeposit(MaryAccount, CreateTransaction("02/03/2014", "Deposit", 90) );
>     RecordWithdraw(MaryAccount, CreateTransaction("04/03/2014", "ATM Withdrawal", 150) );
>     RecordDeposit(MaryAccount, CreateTransaction("05/03/2014", "Deposit", 20) );
>     RecordWithdraw(MaryAccount, CreateTransaction("05/03/2014", "Withdraw", 100) );
>     RecordWithdraw(MaryAccount, CreateTransaction("05/03/2014", "Withdraw", 50) );
>     RecordDeposit(JohnAccount, CreateTransaction("11/03/2014", "Deposit", 20) );
>     RecordDeposit(JohnAccount, CreateTransaction("12/03/2014", "Deposit", 80) );
>     RecordWithdraw(JohnAccount, CreateTransaction("12/03/2014", "Withdraw", 50) );
>     PrintReport(MaryAccount);
>     PrintReport(JohnAccount);
>     return 0;
>     }
>     
>     // the .h file as a struct ass1 section CUSTOMER
>     
>     #ifndef CUSTOMER_H
>     #define CUSTOMER_H
>     
>     using namespace std;
>     
>     struct customer
>     {
>         std::string name;
>         std::string pin;
>         std::string user_id
>     };
>     
>     
>     // function for the above CUSTOMER
>     
>     Customer* CreateCustomer(const string& name, const string& id, const string& pin) {
>         return new Customer { name, id, pin };
>     
>     }
>     
>     
>     // the .h file as a struct ass1 section transaction
>     
>     struct Transaction 
>     
>     {
>         std::string date;
>         std::string description;
>         double amount;
>     };
>     
>     
>     
>     // function for the above transaction
>     
>     
>     transaction* CreateTransaction(const string& date, const string& description, const double& amount) {
>     
>         return new transaction { date, description, amount };
>     
>     }
>     
>     
>     // the .h file as a struct ass1 section account
>     
>     
>         struct Account {
>         Customer customer;
>         int number;
>         double balance, total_deposit, total_withdrawal;
>     
>     // function for the above account 
>     
>     //CreateAccount prototype:
>     
>     
>     Account* CreateAccount(const Customer& customer, const std::string& openingDate = "01/01/2014", const double& openingBalance
> = 0, const double& deposit = 0, const double& withdraw = 0);
```

---

For this assignment the customer struct must be :

> `CustomerName: string UserID: string Pin: string`

Transaction struct must be:

TransactionDate: string
TransactionDescription: string
TransactionAmount: double

Account stuct must be:

Holder: Customer
AccountNo: string
Balance: double
TotalDeposit: double
TotalWithdrawal: double
TransactionList: Transaction[]
TransactionCount: int

The Customer structure (defined in a header file Customer.h) containing three members:
Customer Name, User ID and Pin.

- A function CreateCustomer() that creates a Customer. It has three parameters to initialise
  each member of the structure (Customer Name, User ID, and PinNumber). All parameters
  should have default parameter blank values are to be specified. Prototype:

Customer* CreateCustomer(const string& name, const string& id, const string& pin)

- The Transaction structure (defined in a header file Transaction.h) containing three members:
  Transaction Date, Description and Amount. The Amount can’t be negative value.
- A function CreateTransaction() that creates a Transaction. It has three parameters to initialise each member of the structure (Transaction Date, Description and Amount). All parameters should have default parameter values are to be specified. The Date sets to "01/01/2014", the Description is blank and amount is zero. Prototype:

Transaction* CreateTransaction(const string& date, const string& description, const double& amount))

- The Account structure (defined in a header file Account.h) containing seven members:
  Account Holder, Number, Balance, Total Deposit, Total Withdrawal, Transaction List array of
  maximum 100 records and Transaction count on the existing transaction records.
- A function CreateAccount() that creates an Account. It has six parameters to initialise each
  appropriate member of the structure. The date parameter use to create the first transaction for
  the Transaction List array, the description is Opening balance from the balance parameter.
  Therefore, the Transaction count should be set to one after the Account is created. All
  parameters from the third one should have default parameter values are to be specified. The
  Date sets to "01/01/2014", the balance, deposit and withdraw set to zero value. Prototype:

Account* CreateAccount(const Customer& holder, const string& number, const string& date, const double&
balance, const double& deposit, const double& withdraw)

- A function RecordDeposit() that store the Transaction parameter into the Transaction List
  array of the parameter Account and increasing the Transaction count by one. Make sure to
  check the transaction parameter must have the amount higher than zero. Otherwise, display an
  error message. There is no requiring for the default parameter values.
  void RecordDeposit(Account* account, Transaction* transaction)
- A function RecordWithdraw() that store the Transaction parameter into the Transaction List
  array of the parameter Account and increasing the Transaction count by one. Make sure to
  check the transaction parameter must have the amount higher than zero and less than or equal to
  the parameter account balance. Otherwise, display an error message. There is no requiring for
  the default parameter values.

void RecordWithdraw(Account* account, Transaction* transaction)

- A function PrintReport() that accepts an Account pointer parameter to display the summary
  balance account and the list of Transaction record on the array to displays as the provided output
  format. Prototype:

void PrintReport(Account* account)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to try and give a general structure rather than exact code for clarity of meaning.
Your Account struct needs an array of transactions to store the last 100 transactions. Add a new field to store those (a Transaction[] or Transaction*). In CreateAccount(), set it to be an array 100 long (initialize it). In CreateAccount(), you will also need to set all the fields with the information given in parameters.
In RecordWithdraw() and RecordDeposit(), check if the transaction is legal (allowed by the restrictions provided),then add the new transaction to the next free slot in the transaction array ( determined with transaction#), then update the balance, total withdrawal/deposit, and transaction number of the account. 
Hope this helps.